# How to merge multidimentional array into single array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-merge

I have this array which contains 2 keys and values..

```
array (
  23 => 
  array (
    0 => 9,
    1 => 13,
    2 => 2,
    3 => 11,
    4 => 4,
    5 => 5,
    6 => 6,
    7 => 12,
    8 => 1,
    9 => 7,
    10 => 10,
    11 => 8,
    12 => 3,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 9,
    1 => 13,
    2 => 2,
    3 => 11,
    4 => 4,
    5 => 5,
    6 => 6,
    7 => 14,
    8 => 12,
    9 => 1,
    10 => 7,
    11 => 10,
    12 => 8,
    13 => 3,
  )
)
```

So How can I convert this into single query with distinct values like this

```
array (
  0 => 9,
  1 => 13,
  2 => 2,
  3 => 11,
  4 => 4,
  5 => 5,
  6 => 6,
  7 => 12,
  8 => 1,
  9 => 7,
  10 => 10,
  11 => 8,
  12 => 3,
  20 => 14,
)
```

That means it should be first merge and then create distinct values array without using more **foreach/for loop**.

This is the code I have tried  http://codepad.org/x881cBt1

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array_walk_recursive](http://php.net/array_walk_recursive) to flatten your multidimensional array:

```
$flatten = [];
array_walk_recursive($array, function ($value) use (&$flatten) { 
        $flatten[] = $value; 
});
$flatten = array_unique($flatten); //Taking Unique for the flattened array
print_r($flatten);
```

This should give:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 9
    [1] => 13
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 11
    [4] => 4
    [5] => 5
    [6] => 6
    [7] => 12
    [8] => 1
    [9] => 7
    [10] => 10
    [11] => 8
    [12] => 3
    [20] => 14
)
```

Check [EVAL](https://eval.in/718979)

Comment: How `[12] => 3    [13] => 3` value 3 comes 2 times

Comment: How about `[20] => 14` from where does this 20 key comes from ?

Comment: Check the array that you get before applying `array_unique`. You will find the reason.

Comment: I need to know if you need unique values or unique keys, or what sort of algorithm are you using for your resultant array?

Comment: Well my question just simple from where does this 20 key came from as there is no such key available in given array?

Comment: Well I explained that in comments already - _Check the array that you get before applying array_unique. You will find the reason._ Basically, `flatten` variable has all values from both index in your array. Then we are removing duplicates

Comment: yes I know that this is coming through array_unique but the question is How ? Is php is applying that?

Comment: Yes, `flatten[]` in `array_walk_recursive` means, the index will be automatically generated. Check this [eval](https://eval.in/719012). You will get an idea

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$data; //Your array
$data_set = array_values($data);
$required_data = [];
for ($i=0; $i< count($data_set); $i++) {
    $required_data = array_merge($required_data, $data_set[$i]);
    unset($data_set[$i]);
}
var_dump($required_data);
```

This will solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code  as you said this code is without any loop

```
    $myArray = array (
      23 => 
      array (
        0 => 9,
        1 => 13,
        2 => 2,
        3 => 11,
        4 => 4,
        5 => 5,
        6 => 6,
        7 => 12,
        8 => 1,
        9 => 7,
        10 => 10,
        11 => 8,
        12 => 3,
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        0 => 9,
        1 => 13,
        2 => 2,
        3 => 11,
        4 => 4,
        5 => 5,
        6 => 6,
        7 => 14,
        8 => 12,
        9 => 1,
        10 => 7,
        11 => 10,
        12 => 8,
        13 => 3,
      )
    );

    $objTmp = (object) array('array' => array());

    array_walk_recursive($myArray, create_function('&$v, $k, &$t', '$t->array[] = $v;'), $objTmp);

    print_r (array_unique($objTmp->array));

/* output
Array
(
    [0] => 9
    [1] => 13
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 11
    [4] => 4
    [5] => 5
    [6] => 6
    [7] => 12
    [8] => 1
    [9] => 7
    [10] => 10
    [11] => 8
    [12] => 3
    [20] => 14
)

*/
```

Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr;//Your array
$final_arr=array();
foreach($arr as $r){
$r=array_unique($r);
$final_arr=array_merge($final_arr,$r);
}

$final_arr=array_unique($final_arr);
print_r($final_arr);
```

see it live [ideone](http://ideone.com/na09GF)

Comment: is there any way by with we can ignore the use of foearach() loop

Comment: @Exception go with the method explained by Thamilan above

Answer (score 0):

```
//Here 1st you have to Merge array & then remove duplicate entry

<?php
$main_array=array("0"=>array(1,2,3,4),"1"=>array(2,6,4),"2"=>array(2,8,5));

$temp_array=array();
for($i=0;$i<count($main_array);$i++)
{
$temp_array=array_merge($temp_array,$main_array[$i]);
}

//var_dump($temp_array);
$final_array=array_unique($temp_array);

echo "array:";
var_dump($final_array);
?>
```